# What is required to use android:backgroundTint in Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm really confusing how the android's design/front-end works. A lot of questions are in my mind that, why android not provider easy way/method ( as in html like border-bottom, or in JavaFX) to add borders in textview or something other blah blah. but afraid may be stackoverflow not allowed me ask such question. One question of them which I want to ask here is that what is required to use `android:backgroundTint`

Because in the EditText it is working as simple.

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Edting"
android:backgroundTint="#00FFFF"
 />
```

but in the TextView to work with it or to add the border I have to use a drawable utility.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Edting"
android:backgroundTint="#00FFFF" // not working at all
 />
```

Somewhere I read that it add the shade to background. But why it is changing the bottom-border. So another question could be the actual purpose of `android:backgroundTint`

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: It will be worked for API level `21` and above it.

Comment: @VikasTiwari any specific line or paragraph? related to this topic.

Comment: @Piyush I'm using the same API for both of them. No issue related to `API Level`.